# Some of LD_LIBRARY_PATH do not show up after echo

Tags: ubuntu, zshrc

I have some confusion about exporting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `zshrc` on Ubuntu.

Here is the snippet in my `zshrc`:

```
# ros
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.zsh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# cuda 
export CUDA_HOME=$CUDA_HOME:/usr/local/cuda-11.2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-11.2/lib64

# isaac gym
export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/xzc/mambaforge/envs/mvp/lib

# mujoco
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco210/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco211/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco214/bin

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/nvidia
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
```

After `echo ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`, only `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set after the `isaac gym` comment are shown, that is,

```
/home/xzc/mambaforge/envs/mvp/lib:
/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco200/bin:
/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco210/bin:
/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco211/bin:
/home/xzc/.mujoco/mujoco214/bin:/usr/lib/nvidia
```

In other words, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` under the `ros` and `cuda` comments are not shown. I tried to put both `ros` and `cuda` snippets after `isaac gym` and all `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` show up successfully. But why?

I don't know much about the rules in `zshrc`, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know what `${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:` does in the lines you pasted?  And did you notice that part is missing in the `isaac gym` section?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reminder. I changed the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` in the `Isaac gym` part and everything works. I will learn more about the difference between the `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Thanks!